# Formula that returns all the different text strings in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a row with multiple models of cars. Every model in own cell but models repeat multiple times. I want to create formula in Excel 2010, that returns every different model just once.

Look like these -

JUMPER Bus
JUMPER Box
JUMPER Box
JUMPER Box
DUCATO Box
DUCATO Box
DUCATO Box
ASTRA H
ASTRA H
ASTRA H Saloon
ASTRA H Saloon
ASTRA F CLASSIC Hatchback
ASTRA F CLASSIC Estate
ASTRA G Hatchback
ASTRA G Hatchback

From this I would like to get:

JUMPER Bus
JUMPER Box
DUCATO Box
ASTRA H
ASTRA H Saloon
ASTRA F CLASSIC Hatchback
ASTRA F CLASSIC Estate
ASTRA G Hatchback

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Highlight your table and go to the ribbon and to *Data - Sort & Filter - Advanced* and check the box next to "unique records only".

This will filter the list only showing unique values based on the columns you select.

Comment: @user3165896 if this answer solved your problem, be sure to click the checkmark next to it to indicate your question was answered so others can skip over it when looking to unanswered questions.